# Eclipse JSON format

Tags: javascript, json, eclipse

I'm using a JSON file to store an array of rectangle attributes. Then, in a separate javascript file, I parse the JSON and draw the rectangles on a canvas.
For some reason, Eclipse likes this JSON format and the Chrome debugger accepts it:

```
rectangles = '[{"x" : 0, "y" : 0, "width" : 20, "height" : 10, "color" : "red"}, {"x" : 25, "y" : 0, "width" : 20, "height" : 10, "color" : "blue"}, {"x" : 0, "y" : 15, "width" : 20, "height" : 10, "color" : "blue"}, {"x" : 25, "y" : 15, "width" : 20, "height" : 10, "color" : "red"}]';
```

but when I clean it up and try to format it, Eclipse no longer draws the rectangles with this format:

```
rectangles='[
  {
    "x": 0,
    "y": 0,
    "width": 20,
    "height": 10,
    "color": "red"
  },
  {
    "x": 25,
    "y": 0,
    "width": 20,
    "height": 10,
    "color": "blue"
  },
  {
    "x": 0,
    "y": 15,
    "width": 20,
    "height": 10,
    "color": "blue"
  },
  {
    "x": 25,
    "y": 15,
    "width": 20,
    "height": 10,
    "color": "red"
  }
]';
```

Is there a reason why it only draws the rectangles with the former format?
For reference, here is my javascript:

```
function load(){
  var myData = JSON.parse(rectangles);
  var can = document.getElementById('rectangleCanvas');
  var context = can.getContext('2d');

  for (i=0; i<myData.length; i++){
    context.fillStyle = myData[i].color;
    context.fillRect(myData[i].x, myData[i].y, myData[i].width, myData[i].height);
  }
}
```

Comment: basic debugging: `console.log(myData)` with both formats and see how they differ.

Comment: Even if it is not valid JSON, how come Eclipse recognizes the first format?

Comment: well, maybe `rectangles` isn't a global var, so it's undefined at the point you try doing it with the manual string, causing nothing to be parsed. so... check `console.log` to see what's REALLY happening, instead of assuming it's the prettyprinting at fault.

Comment: @MarcB console.log(myData) isn't popping up with anything

Comment: so work your way backwards. `console.log(rectangles)`.

Answer (score 2):

If you want the string to extend across lines you have to end the string and add:

```
var myLongString = 'This' +
    'is' +
    'my long string.';
```

I plopped your "cleaned-up" `rectangles` into a [jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/Lwryk4a0/) and you can see the console log the error:

> SyntaxError: unterminated string literal

Comment: So I have to add after every line in the JSON file?

Comment: JSON files don't need this. JavaScript does, however. So if you just fetch the JSON from a file, you should be alright. Additionally, if you get it from a file, it should already be JSON, not a string.

Answer (score 0):

For your specific error check [Tony's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/30579922/636561).

By the way, from your snippet appears strange that you declare it as a String and then parse it later, though.

Why not this?

```
rectangles = [
    {
        "x": 0,
        "y": 0,
        "width": 20,
        "height": 10,
        "color": "red"
    },
    {
        "x": 25,
        "y": 0,
        "width": 20,
        "height": 10,
        "color": "blue"
    },
    {
        "x": 0,
        "y": 15,
        "width": 20,
        "height": 10,
        "color": "blue"
    },
    {
        "x": 25,
        "y": 15,
        "width": 20,
        "height": 10,
        "color": "red"
    }
];

function load(){

    var can = document.getElementById('rectangleCanvas');
    var context = can.getContext('2d');

    for (i=0; i<rectangles.length; i++){
        context.fillStyle = rectangles[i].color;
        context.fillRect(rectangles[i].x, rectangles[i].y, rectangles[i].width, rectangles[i].height);
    }
}
```

Comment: yes, but OP is using JSON.parse, there the json string **HAS** to be a string. can't json.parse an actual JS array/object... that object should be coming from a web call, and coming in as json.

Comment: You are right, the problem must be something else. Probably the variable scope.

Comment: I agree it makes way more sense to just use JSON. But, it's unclear as to how `rectangles` is being instantiated.

Comment: I am with you, but it seems just a kind of exercise. I've upvoted your answer.

Comment: I'd use @LucaFagioli suggested method, but the JSON is always going to be in an external file for this particular case.